# How to declare fields?

Tags: scope, gtk, vala

I write a GUI program in Vala. When I compile it, compiler produces this error:

```
The name e1 does not exist in the context of Subtract.minus
```

The code is:

```
using Gtk;
class Subtract:Window{
    public Subtract(){
        this.title="Subtract program";
        this.destroy.connect(Gtk.main_quit);
        var e1=new Entry();
        var e2=new Entry();
        var lbl=new Label("Result");
        var btn=new Button.with_label("Subtract");
        var box=new Box(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL,5);
        box.add(e1);
        box.add(e2);
        box.add(lbl);
        box.add(btn);
        this.add(box);
        btn.clicked.connect(minus);
    }
    public void minus(){
        int a=int.parse(e1.get_text());
        int b=int.parse(e2.get_text());
        int result=a-b;
        lbl.set_label(result.to_string());
    }
    public static int main(string[]args){
        Gtk.init(ref args);
        var win=new Subtract();
        win.show_all();
        Gtk.main();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

How can I make the variables accessible from the `minus` method.

Comment: I've never used Vala, but I assume Subtract is the class scope in which e1 is created, and minus is a member of that class. How does Vala handle class scope for variables?

Comment: Your `e1` and `e2` variables are local to the `Subtract()` constructor. You need to declare them within the `Subtract` class instead. (I assume you are familiar with a language like Python or Ruby where instance variables are defined within functions; that isn't how Vala works. You will need to declare them alongside the methods.)

Comment: i dont know how i declare them in vala language.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the variables for your widgets (at least `e1`, `e2` and `lbl`) as fields:

```cs
using Gtk;

class Subtract: Window {

    // Fields (sometimes also called "attributes")
    private Entry e1;
    private Entry e2;
    private Label lbl;
    private Button btn;
    private Box box;

    public Subtract () {
        title = "Subtract program";
        destroy.connect (Gtk.main_quit);
        // You don't have to use "this." to access fields in Vala
        // I.e. "this.e1" is equivalent to "e1" in the code below
        e1 = new Entry ();
        e2 = new Entry ();
        lbl = new Label ("Result");
        btn = new Button.with_label ("Subtract");
        box = new Box (Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, 5);
        box.add (e1);
        box.add (e2);
        box.add (lbl);
        box.add (btn);
        add (box);
        btn.clicked.connect (minus);
    }

    public void minus () {
        // The compiler happily accepts "e1" (etc.) here now
        // since I have declared them as fields
        int a = int.parse (e1.get_text ());
        int b = int.parse (e2.get_text ());
        int result = a - b;
        lbl.set_label (result.to_string ());
    }

    public static int main (string[] args) {
        Gtk.init (ref args);
        var win = new Subtract ();
        win.show_all ();
        Gtk.main ();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

PS: The correct technical term is "scope" here. Your code had the variables at the scope of the constructor, my code as the variables as class scoped fields which makes them visible across all the methods of the class.

The Vala compiler calls it "context", which is roughly the same in this case.

Comment: please correct this program so that i understand my problem. because there are less tutorial for vala.

Comment: I have corrected your code. The code in my answer works fine, the key point is the private attribute declaration at the beginning of the class. This is similar to C++ / C# / Java and other languages, btw.

Comment: It is also covered in the Vala tutorial: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tutorial#Basics-1

Comment: if you dont mind, have you any id such as google plus, telegram. i have an telegram id. you can contact with me. Jens Mühlenhoff. my telegram id is "rahilin"

Comment: You can join the Vala IRC channel if you want: irc://irc.gimp.org/vala My nick is "jensm".